# CRASH /duplicity-full.20230105T083600Z.manifest /duplicity-full.20230105T083600Z.vol20.difftar.gz

Tags: permissions, backup, root, swap, duplicity

I had a major crash of files shown above multiplying. could not get in laptop for days. running latest ubuntu jelly which not as satisfied with as 20.04. planning on running a virus scan.?

Any one have idea why files from internet would accumulate like this? There were rows and rows of the duplicity. they were all over my desktop and could not delete at first. also, having trouble in command line with pw...but I know correct pw.  just changed the old pw to a new one after being able to get back in.   anyway also cannot access ROOT file as "not admin permissions"  I am the OWNER and only one on this laptop.
also backups have continuously been failing. On a Lenovo machine.

Is this a virus?  thanks!

Comment: Crashes are rarely the result of viruses unless you’re doing things that expose you to sketchy sources of data. You may want to check your logs to see why Duplicity is crashing so often.

Comment: ok thx.  trying to understand the CAUSE. thx do i do that in the command line?

Comment: I DO NOT visit sketchy realms. so we can eliminate that.

Comment: The logs you are looking for are in `/var/log`. `syslog` would be a good place to start.